# C++ list iterator to integer conversion?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Hello guys I have a list iterator type which I want to convert to UINT.

```
std::set<UINT> volSet;
UINT ssidBase = 1;
UINT ssidEnd = 2;
volSet.insert( ssidBase );
volSet.insert (ssidEnd);
UINT ssidStart =  evf::volSet.begin();
```

I want the first value in the volSet to be set to ssidStart. I'm getting an error when I run this?

```
cannot convert 'std::_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<unsigned int, std::less< unsigned int>, std::allocator< unsigned int>, false> >::iterator' to 'UINT' in initialization
```

Any help is appreciated?

Comment: you should check what begin() is returning and what type assignment you are trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As such, iterators in C++ are basically pointers.

So the general idea is that you need to [dereference](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) that iterator to access the actual value it points to, like so:

```
UINT number = *(container.begin());
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear exactly what the intention is with inserting a one and then a two.  Granted many more unsigned values can be inserted later.  However, by inserting a one, the only other possible value that will be lower is zero.  The insert method for the STL set, map, unordered_set, and unordered_map containers (now called Standard Library) returns a pair.

Insert method reference links:
set
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/insert/

map
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/

unordered_set
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/insert/

unordered_map
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/insert/

If the element already exists in a set, the first pair element is the iterator pointing to the existing element with the second element set to false.  With a successful insert (e.g. the key is not already present in the set), the first element of the pair points to the element that has been successfully added, with the second pair element set to true.

Using a set to guarantee the first (lowest) element (e.g. where the begin() method will always return an iterator pointing to unless the set is empty), does guarantee that the lowest value in the set is always found in constant time (e.g. O(1); big Oh of one).

A coding example with some values in C++11.

```
std::set<UINT> volSet;
pair <std::set<UINT>::itertor, bool> p;

//
// Using the same notation on unsigned int for consistency,
// insert 500 unsigned values into the volSet container.
//
for (UINT i = 500; i >= 0; i--)
{
    p = volSet.insert(i);
    if (p.second == false)
    {
       cerr << "volSet insertion warning!! The value for volSet already has: ";
       cerr << i << endl;
    }
}


//
// Do business logic, deletions/insertions from/to the volSet, and so on...
//
// Now obtain the lowest value inside the volSet and set it to a local variable.
// It is assumed that evf is a user defined namespace.
//
std::set<UINT>::iterator ii = evf::volSet.begin();
UINT ssidStart =  *ii;


//
// Alternatively, implement without declaring a local iterator as Victor
// has shown above.  Note that the parenthesis here are important.  The call
// to begin() has to occur prior to the dereference operator call.
// Note that the sample above intentionally sets the ii iterator 
// before dereferencing.
//
UNIT lowValue = *(evf::volSet.begin());
```

I hope this is helpful to understand the difference between iterators and container elements.